# Function which is analytic except for countably many vertical lines and continuous also there

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Suppose I have a function $f$ of which we know that it is analytic in the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$, where $$S := \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty S_n :=  \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Im(z) = (2n+1) \pi \}.$$
(The set $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$ is thus nearly all of the space $\mathbb{C}$ except countably many vertical lines.)

Suppose also that $f$ is bounded and continuous in the whole complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

**Question**: From these assumptions, does it follow that $f$ is actually analytic in all of $\mathbb{C}$? Below is my attempt to prove that it does. Does my proof seem valid? Is there an essentially easier way of proving it?

**My proof:** I assume it does, and my attempt to prove it is the following: Fix $z \in S_n$ for a fixed $n$ and consider the disk $B(z,1)$ which intersects with exactly one $S_n$, so $B(z,1) = U_1 \cup (B(z,1) \cap S_n) \cup U_2$, where $U_1$ is an open set above $S_n$ and $U_2$ is an open set below $S_n$. Now take a closed, positively directed curve $\gamma \in B(z,1)$, and denote the area it surrounds by $A$.
By Morera's theorem it's enough to prove that $\oint_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$.

If $\gamma$ doesn't intersect $S_n$ we are ready by Cauchy's integral theorem, so assume it does. Now let $T = S_n \cap A$, and split $\gamma$ into $\gamma = \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$, where $\gamma_1$ is in $A_1 \cup S_n$, and $\gamma_2$ is in $A_2 \cup S_n$, and $\gamma_i$ are positively directed closed curves. Now $$\oint_\gamma f(z) dz = \oint_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz + \oint_{\gamma_2} f(z) dz$$

For each of these integrals, we may slighly move $\gamma_i$ so that it doesn't intersect $S_n$ and so that the integral changes with less than a given $\varepsilon$. This is possible, since $f$ is uniformly continuous in the compact set $\overline{B(z,2)}$ and $\gamma_i$ has a finite length. By Cauchy's integral theorem, the new integrals with the moved curves is $0$. We get that $| \oint_\gamma f(z) dz | < 2 \varepsilon$ and so it is zero.

Thus $f$ is analytic in $B(z,1)$, and since $z$ was arbitrary, it's analytic everywhere.

*Remark:* from Liouville's theorem it now follows that $f$ is actually constant.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: This is the symmetry principle and is valid more generally; another proof (not sure if it qualifies as simpler) would be to take the Cauchy integrals on $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ above and notice that say the first one is $f(z), z \in U_1, 0, z \in U_2$, add them so the parts on the line cancel out, while the result is now anayltic in the full open disc and coincides with $f$ outside the part of the line, hence $f$ analytic there too

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the symmetry principle! I bumped into another problem, but resolved it now.

Comment: happy to be of help - as noted the result holds under more general conditions (Jordan domains etc)